# Attributed Text View that opens address in new map view

Tags: ios, uitextview, apple-maps

I'm working on an app that uses parse as the backend and allows users to post their address via text view. I enabled the "Addresses" attribute and addresses open in the Apple maps app. Instead I'd like to keep my users in my app by opening a new view with a map and the address they tapped pinned to the map view.

Is there anyway I can do this without making things overly complicated?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Are you trying to avoid creating map view? There's a lot of examples on how to create a view controller with map view, that show one address. Do you want me to post one here?

Comment: I want to create a map view that intercepts the attributed text view address and displays it with a pin at that location. The map view would have to be able to change, based on whatever a user typed in, not just a static one. Thanks @asaf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can implement the UITextViewDelegate method:

```
- (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldInteractWithURL:(NSURL *)URL inRange:(NSRange)characterRange;
```

> Description: Asks the delegate if the specified text view should allow
>   user interaction with the given URL in the given range of text.
>
> The text view calls this method if the user taps or long-presses the
>   URL link. Implementation of this method is optional. By default, the
>   text view opens the application responsible for handling the URL type
>   and passes it the URL. You can use this method to trigger an
>   alternative action, such as displaying the web content at the URL in a
>   web view within the current application.

[Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextViewDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITextViewDelegate/textView:shouldInteractWithURL:inRange:)

Ex:

1. Make sure your class conforms to: `<UITextViewDelegate>`
2. Set your textview delegate: `[textView setDelegate:self];`
3. Implement the delegate method:

...

```
#pragma mark - UITextViewDelegate

- (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldInteractWithURL:(NSURL *)URL inRange:(NSRange)characterRange { 
    // Open custom map using data from textView.text. 
}
```